# Getting calculation into struct field type of char

Tags: c

I have declared following struct

```
typedef struct STRUCT{
    char calculation[30];
}STRUCT;
```

I have a function:

```
int add_number(int num1, STRUCT *pointer) {
   int integer;
   int sum;
   printf("\nGive an integer to be added: ");
   scanf("%d", &integer);
   sum = num1 + integer;
   printf("%d+%d=%d\n", num1, integer, sum);
   scanf("%s", pointer->calculation);   // here I would want to get the %d+%d=%d stored into pointer->calculation 
   num1 = sum;
   return num1;
}
```

I would want to store this:

```
"%d+%d=%d\n", num1, integer, sum
```

into this:

```
pointer->calculation
```

(So for example, if `num1 = 1` and `integer = 2` I would want to have `3 = 1 + 2` stored into `pointer->calculation`)

How could it be done? I don't get it.

Comment: Use `sprintf` - similar to `printf` but into a buffer.

Comment: Please focus on your problem. You've indicated both `1 + 2 = 3` and `3 = 1 + 2`. To succeed at coding, you have to pay attention to even these trivialities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.g. [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to print a formatted string into a buffer (similar to what `printf` does but instead of directly to stdout).

**For example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1 = 1;
    int integer = 2;
    int sum = num1 + integer;
    char buf[30];
    snprintf(buf, 29, "%d+%d=%d\n", num1, integer, sum);
    printf(buf);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1+2=3
```

The size passed to `snprintf` is 29 instead of 30, because we need to keep one element for the zero termination of the string.

**Note:** you wrote that you would like the buffer to contain `3 = 1 + 2` which does not match your string format `"%d+%d=%d\n"`, so I assume you meant you'd like `1+2=3`.

Comment: Thank you! However, this is a school assignment and I'm required to use the typedef struct -statement to complete this, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use the typedef struct. Simply replace `buf` in my code with `pointer->calculation`. Any such char array can be used.

Comment: Thanks! What about fgets(pointer->calculation, 30, stdin). Now that I think about it, shouldn't it work too?

Comment: `fget` requires a `FILE*`. see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets.